# How to parse gmail with specific subject line and get populated in the google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

The Code which i have tried is not able to get the email with specific subject line please let me know what is the mistake in the script mentioned below

Tried the Below mentioned Script but still not working:

```
function amy() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject: "New submission from Free Diagnosis*"');
  var a=[];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      a[j]=parseMail(messages[j].getPlainBody());
    }
  }
  var nextRow=s.getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;
  var numRows=a.length;
  var numCols=a[0].length;
  s.getRange(nextRow,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(a);
}
```

Comment: The * at the end of Diagnosis does not signify anything